# How could reuse spel code of spring Cacheable annotation?

Tags: spring-annotations, spring-cache

There is a customer annotation `Auth`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Auth {
    String condition() default "";
}
```

in some cases do not auth, e.g. if count is less than and equals 5

```
@Auth(condition = "#count > 5")
public List<Book> findBooks(int count)
```

How could directly reuse `@Cacheable` infrastructure code and do not need redevelopment?

```
@Cacheable(value="book", condition="#name.length < 32")
public Book findBook(String name)
```

Comment: Do you want to use `@Cacheable` in place of `@Auth` if I get the question correct ? I doubt if I got the question correctly !

Comment: No I just want reuse  spel parsing ability  of `@Cacheable` and do not want reinvent the wheel. The requirement is just that if meets the condition do something or do something else